# VNC connection in Debian only opening some programs

Tags: debian, vnc

So it took me some efforts to get the TigerVNC server running correctly (Colors displaying strangely, small errors), but I have it working now.

However, when I try opening certain programs, the program just spins or a few moments and then closes.

Works:

- Firefox
- Xterm (Had to install this)

What doesn't work:

- Terminal
- Mail Program
- Files
- Help
- LibreOffice

I've configured VNC servers in the past with no issues like this. Curious if anyone has encountered this?

You'll see in the screenshot here xterm is open, but libreoffice just spinning at the top but never opens.

UPDATE: So I jumped over to my main session (Using the console in proxmox for Debian) and I see everything I tried opening in the VNC session, but can't see it in the VNC session. So this definitely has to do with some configuration in the VNC session, just not sure what

[image]

Comment: And when you try run libreoffice from that xterm terminal? Isn't there any message?

Comment: I don't run it from xterm. I open the gnome "Activities" window (Top left) and select it from the favorites bar

Comment: I know, and I'm saying in other words: Try it and watch output in terminal.

Comment: Typed ```libreoffice --writer new_doc.odt``` from xterm.

It just hangs. No message